# Remove text files with less than three lines

Tags: bash, text, awk

I'm using an Awk script to split a big text document into independent files. I did it and now I'm working with 14k text files. The problem here is there are a lot of files with just three lines of text and it's not useful for me to keep them.

I know I can delete lines in a text with `awk 'NF>=3' file`, but I don't want to delete lines inside files, rather I want to delete files which content is just two or three text lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to modify your existing script to just not create files with 3 or less lines?

Comment: Yeah, totally. The problem is I have had a lot of troubles running the script and I had to modify it several times to extract all the files I wanted to. It's not the most elegant solution but oh well. Anyway, the solution RavinderSigh gave me fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following `find`command.(tested with GNU `awk`)

```
find /your/path/ -type f -exec awk -v lines=3 'NR>lines{f=1; exit} END{if (!f) print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

So above will print file names who are having lesser than 3 lines on console. Once you are happy with results coming then try following to delete them. Only once you are ok with above command's output run following and even ***I will suggest run below command in a test directory first and once you are fully satisfied then proceed with below one.***(remove `echo` from below I have still put it for safer side :) )

```
find /your/path/ -type f -exec awk -v lines=3 'NR>lines{f=1; exit} END{exit !f}' {} \; -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: `END {}` is always executed, even if script is terminated by `exit`. So all filenames printed. Anyway, exit status works.

Comment: @Wiimm, thank you for letting me know, I have fixed it now.

Comment: @Ed Morton, IMHO reason behind putting `NR==3` since OP told lesser than 3 lines and I believe when we use `NR>3` it may take files which are having 3 lines too for deletion, kindly correct me if I am wrong here. Thank you for as always your guidance :)

Comment: The OP wants to remove files that have **3 or less** lines, not just less than 3 lines. Consider your first script. If NR gets to 4 then f is set to 1 and the script exits without printing a FILENAME. If NR never reaches 4 (i.e. it is 3 or less) then f is never set and so the script prints the FILENAME. That's exactly what you want to happen since you're trying to generate a list of files to remove. Similar logic for your 2nd script.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure Ed sir got it, thank you for nice explanation, have a nice weekend ahead:)

Comment: Okay this solution solved all my problems. It worked perfectly! And yeah I wanted to delete every file that have 3 or less lines. I modified the script to see which one solved it in a satisfactory way and voilá, all my problems are gone :D. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If the files in the current directory are all text files, this should be efficient and portable:

```
for f in *; do 
    [ $(head -4 "$f" | wc -l) -lt 4 ] && echo "$f"
done  # | xargs rm
```

Inspect the list, and if it looks OK, then remove the `#` on the last line to actually delete the unwanted files.

Why use `head -4`? Because `wc` doesn't know when to quit. Suppose half of the text files were each more than a terabyte long; if that were the case `wc -l` alone would be quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `wc` to calculate lines and then decide either to delete the file or not. you should write a shell script instead of just `awk` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl. The below solution will be efficient as the file handle ARGV will be closed if the line count > 3

```
 perl -nle ' close(ARGV) if ($.>3) ; $kv{$ARGV}++; END { for(sort keys %kv) { print if $kv{$_}>3 } } ' *
```

If you want to pipe the output of some other command (say find) you can use it like

```
$ find . -name "*" -type f -exec perl -nle ' close(ARGV) if ($.>3) ; $kv{$ARGV}++; END { for(sort keys %kv) { print if $kv{$_}>3 } } ' {} \;
./bing.fasta
./chris_smith.txt
./dawn.txt
./drcatfish.txt
./foo.yaml
./ip.txt
./join_tab.pl
./manoj1.txt
./manoj2.txt
./moose.txt
./query_ip.txt
./scottc.txt
./seats.ksh
./tane.txt
./test_input_so.txt
./ya801.txt

$
```

the output of wc -l * on the same directory

```
$ wc -l *
  12 bing.fasta
  16 chris_smith.txt
   8 dawn.txt
   9 drcatfish.txt
   3 fileA
   3 fileB
  13 foo.yaml
   3 hubbs.txt
   8 ip.txt
  19 join_tab.pl
   6 manoj1.txt
   6 manoj2.txt
   5 moose.txt
  17 query_ip.txt
   3 rororo.txt
   5 scottc.txt
  22 seats.ksh
   1 steveman.txt
   4 tane.txt
  13 test_input_so.txt
  24 ya801.txt
 200 total

$
```